# How can I launch safari browser from iPad application?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

Need to launch safari from ipad application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];
```

Comment: but how will i get the object of SAFARI browser here?

Comment: What do you mean by "object"...

Comment: I want the instance of SAFARI browser which is getting open.

Comment: So you want to know what opened in Safari and then Open it to your browser :)

Comment: I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: i want to remove navigation controls of SAFARI after it opened.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Comment: but how will i get the object of SAFARI browser here?